# What does Microsoft C/C++ Optimizing Compiler compile down to

Tags: c++, c

I was just curious by default does Microsoft's C/C++ Optimizing Compiler compile down to machine language or byte code?

Comment: What's your understanding of "machine language" and "byte code"?

Comment: Very little, just started a class on Operating systems

Comment: It compiles down to intermediate code internally.  Which a generic code generator, the 2nd stage, then converts to optimized machine code.  Or IL.  Very common in compiler design, the code optimizer and generator stage is a heavy investment.  Not actually very visible, beyond the DLLs and temp files it uses, easiest to just think of direct to machine code translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It compiles down to machine language (microprocessor opcodes) by default, or [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), using the `/clr` switch.

For comparison, C# and Visual Basic compile to [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), and Visual Basic 6 can compile to either P-code (a form of byte code) or native code (machine language).

Comment: My head, and three other community members who agreed via their upvotes.  See http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson20/p6.html. and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx.  See Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639(v=vs.80).aspx, and http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/p-codeversusnativecode.htm. "Native" means machine instructions.

Comment: Thanks didn't mean to call you out on the credibility, this is more for my professor. I normally trust what i see here on SO

Answer (score 3):

It can do both.

By default it produces native machine code.
With the /clr command line option it will produce .NET IL byte code.